# Make menu and submenu into reusable function

Tags: php

What basically am trying to do here is create menu and submenu which can be hooked from anywhere in the script which means that I can add new menu from anywhere in the script. What I want to do now create a reusable function for it.

**On menu.php**

```
function add_admin_menu($admin_menu_page = array()){
    return $admin_menu_page;
}

function add_admin_submenu($admin_submenu_page = array()){
    return $admin_submenu_page;
}

$admin_menu_page[] = array("Dashboard", "dashboard");
$admin_menu_page[] = array("Pages", "pages");
$admin_menu_page[] = array("Setings", "setings");

$admin_submenu_page['dashboard'][] = array("Home", "home");
$admin_submenu_page['dashboard'][] = array("Update", "update");

$admin_submenu_page['pages'][] = array("Add New Page", "new");
$admin_submenu_page['pages'][] = array("All Pages", 'pages');

$admin_submenu_page['setings'][] = array("SMTP", "smtp");
$admin_submenu_page['setings'][] = array("Theme Options", "theme-options"); 

add_admin_menu($admin_menu_page);
add_admin_submenu($admin_submenu_page);
```

**On index.php**

```
var_dump(add_admin_menu());
```

and the output is

> array(0) { }

What am I missing?

In a simple question how will I make this into function?

Comment: Everything you wrote here is wrong and won't ever work, you just send your arrays into the void

Comment: Probably you are using this var_dump(add_admin_menu()); some where out of scope ... please share code where you are debuging this array.

Comment: @AdilAbbasi no he just did not store them

Comment: I' am dumping it in index.php page and am storing it in menu.php page. Above code is everything I have in relation to this issue.

Comment: @user3140617 no you're not, you just returning the value back

Comment: `var_dump(add_admin_menu());` you are not passing an array in `add_admin_menu()` there for you are returning nothing, if you want a result you need to `var_dump(add_admin_menu($admin_menu_page));`

Comment: Good point, let me something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store your values, perhaps like that:

```
function add_admin_menu($admin_menu_page = array()){
  static $menu = array();

  if(empty($menu)) $menu = $admin_menu_page;

  return $menu;
}
```

The pitfall of that solution that there will be only one menu at the time;

That way you can store any amount of menus you want;

```
$menus = array();

function add_admin_menu($admin_menu_page = array()){
  global $menus;

  $index = sizeof($menus);

  $menus[$index] = $admin_menu_page;

  return $index;
}
```

Note that it's returning an `$index`, not input array(makes no sense), so you can access that menu later and even relate it with some sumbenu.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, if you are trying to check what is passed to array.

```
function add_admin_menu($admin_menu_page = array()){
  var_dump($admin_menu_page);
  return $admin_menu_page;
}
```

But didn't got any reason for this function what it is doing returning the same array.

Try this if you want to var_dump after calling function.

```
$menu = add_admin_menu($admin_menu_page);
$submenu = add_admin_submenu($admin_submenu_page);
var_dump($menu);
var_dump($submenu);
```

Comment: hi I have already test this and it var_dump does show all the array informations from add_admin_menu function

Comment: then for what you are looking ? do want to dump array after calling funcion.